# Kivy: How to check the location of a drag behavior item

Tags: python, kivy

Not much code yet, but I am trying to make the buttons stay if they are on the right side, but if they are on the left, to disappear. I am not sure if this is possible, but if you are able to help, I would love it!
main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button


Builder.load_file('main.kv')


class DragButton(DragBehavior, Button):
    pass


class MainScreen(Widget):
    pass


class WorkingApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    WorkingApp().run()
```

​
main.kv

```
<DragButton>
    drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    drag_timeout: 10000
    drag_distance: 0
    text: 'Hi'
    size_hint: (1, .5)

<MainScreen>
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                text: 'Widgets'
                size_hint: (1, .25)
            
            DragButton:
            
            DragButton:

            DragButton:


        Splitter:
            sizable_from: 'left'
            Label:
                text: 'Check If they are here'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to bind a method to the `center_x` property of the `DragButtons`. That method can then check the position of the `DragButton`, and remove it, if it is to the right of the `Splitter`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button


Builder.load_file('main.kv')


class DragButton(DragBehavior, Button):
    pass


class MainScreen(Widget):
    splitter = ObjectProperty(None)
    boxlayout = ObjectProperty(None)

    def dragged(self, dragButton):
        if dragButton.center_x > self.splitter.x:
            self.boxlayout.remove_widget(dragButton)


class WorkingApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    WorkingApp().run()
```

with some small modifications to the 'kv':

```
<DragButton>
    drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    drag_timeout: 10000
    drag_distance: 0
    text: 'Hi'
    size_hint: (1, .5)

<MainScreen>
    splitter: split
    boxlayout: box
    
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        BoxLayout:
            id: box
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                text: 'Widgets'
                size_hint: (1, .25)
            
            DragButton:
                on_center_x: root.dragged(self)
            
            DragButton:
                on_center_x: root.dragged(self)

            DragButton:
                on_center_x: root.dragged(self)


        Splitter:
            id: split
            sizable_from: 'left'
            Label:
                text: 'Check If they are here'
```

Key modifications are the addition of `ids` in the `kv` for the `Splitter` and the `BoxLayout` and methods bound to the `center_x` property of each `DragButton`. In the python, `ObjectProperties` for those new `ids` and the `dragged()` method are added to the `MainScreen` class. The `dragged()` method just checks if the center of the `DragButton` is roght of the `Splitter` and removes that `DragButton` if it is.